# number of files in linux using shell script( if no output Error should not come)

Tags: linux, shell

I am getting file count using `z=ls -1| wc -l`
but when no files are there, it throws an error as *no files **found*** but I don't want that error, I just want `0` in `'z'` variable

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `ls -1| wc -l` gives me `0` on Ubuntu Linux. Are you sure the error is coming from that line?

Comment: Post The error you are getting here

Answer (score 0):

Everything works just fine:

```
z=`ls -1 |wc -l`
echo $z

0
```

Comment: Its actually not when you sure as a shell script